# stop couchdb daemon

Tags: services, couchdb

I have `Apache CouchDB` installed on Ubuntu 14.04 x64, but I'm not able to stop it.
I tried all of these

```
couchdb -d
couchdb -k
```

but none works. What I mean is that, when I run the above commands and then check the status using `couchdb -s`, it returns the promising

```
Apache CouchDB is not running.
```

Then, if I try to query the web service using `curl http://localhost:5984`, it returns the usual welcome message

```
{"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"f682066cac8371ee6ad994429312b2f8","version":"1.6.1","vendor":{"version":"14.04","name":"Ubuntu"}}
```

Also

```
$>sudo netstat -tlpn | grep 5984
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5984          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1272/beam.smp  
So, how can I start/stop it? Also, how can I prevent it from automatically start at boot-time?
```

Lastly, scanning the active processes, this is the output:

```
$>ps aux | grep couchdb
root      1022  0.0  0.0  98676   340 ?        Ss   apr09   0:00 su couchdb -c /usr/bin/couchdb
couchdb   1272  0.1  0.1 1005024 10600 ?       Ssl  apr09   3:43 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-5.10.4/bin/beam.smp -Bd -K true -A 4 -- -root /usr/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /var/lib/couchdb -- -noshell -noinput -os_mon start_memsup false start_cpu_sup false disk_space_check_interval 1 disk_almost_full_threshold 1 -sasl errlog_type error -couch_ini /etc/couchdb/default.ini /etc/couchdb/local.ini -s couch
couchdb   1698  0.0  0.0   4440   328 ?        Ss   apr09   0:05 sh -s disksup
```

Comment: Did you run couchdb -d, couchdb -k and couchdb -s as root? AFAIK, you cannot kill the processes of other users unless you are root.

Comment: both normally and as root, same results.

Comment: Also, I've updated my answer with the results from `netstat`